# Show More javascript which expands marquee

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a stock-ticker (slowly but surely as I am learning javascript)

It seems to be working well, and I am now trying to style the ticker so it has a "show more" button. The "show more" text needs to sit outside of the marquee, when clicked it will expand the marquee showing the full list (or so many px). The text will change to show less once it has been clicked which would reduce the marquee back to its default size.

I have experimented with a few different javascript scripts taken from the web but to no avail. I'm not sure if the marquee tag is causing issues.

A similar example of what I am trying to achieve can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8u2jF/

but i cannot get it working with the marquee or my existing JS

My current project which I need to inegrate this into can also be found here:

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLsy7zak/5/

```
var gstock = ["EPA:PIG","LON:AHT","NYSE:URI","NYSE:TEX" ,"NYSE:CAT", "NASDAQ:HEES",  "VIE:PAL" ];
$(document).ready(function () {
       for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q="+gstock[i]+"&callback=?", function (response) {
            var stockInfo1 = response[0];
            var divContainer =  $('*[data-symbol="' + stockInfo1.t +'"]');

            var stockString1 = '<div class="stockWrapper">' + divContainer.data('title') + ':';
            var stockName1 = stockInfo1.t;             
            var stockChange ="";
            stockString1  += '<span class="stockSymbol "> '  +  stockInfo1.t + ' </span>';
            stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "> '  +  stockInfo1.l  + '</span>';
            stockChange += '<span class="stockChange "> '  +  stockInfo1.c + '</span>';
            stockString1 += stockChange + '</div>';
            $("#title").append("<div>" + divContainer.data('title') + "</div>");
            $("#symbols").append("<div><b>" + stockInfo1.t + "</b></div>");

            $("#liveData").append("<div>" + stockChange + "</div>");
            divContainer.append(stockString1);

        });
    }
});
```

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the marquee. I tried to increase the height of the marquee and what it does is - it resets the animation causing an unwanted effect.

Instead, I wrote some quick code using CSS3 animation and replicated what you needed. Here is the fiddle to look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/arun88m/9og8qnkL/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="marquee">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse libero nulla, venenatis in suscipit vitae, euismod non mauris. Quisque sagittis nulla neque, at blandit leo porttitor nec. Praesent quis dolor venenatis, pellentesque eros volutpat, suscipit mi. Sed luctus diam est, vel egestas felis lacinia quis. Curabitur vel mattis urna. In convallis ex mauris, in condimentum purus porta vel. Cras id molestie odio. Proin rutrum, tortor eget varius ultricies, odio enim congue purus, nec porta massa nunc at diam. Cras efficitur ipsum a ligula ornare, vel eleifend nulla iaculis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec tempor quam nec aliquet gravida. Proin porttitor convallis ipsum vitae aliquam. Nunc mollis, dui nec dignissim accumsan, erat erat dictum magna, non tristique felis massa non nibh. Aenean ullamcorper eget velit eget auctor.

Donec pharetra ante sit amet accumsan molestie. Mauris mollis hendrerit augue, non vestibulum eros. Aliquam vitae quam faucibus, dapibus nisi ac, vulputate sapien. Fusce bibendum, purus eget sodales blandit, lectus est bibendum diam, sit amet dapibus purus justo nec risus. Fusce dignissim nulla sed risus efficitur, sed porta nulla efficitur. Aenean rhoncus, velit eu porta ornare, massa tellus dapibus diam, quis sagittis tellus justo sed purus. Fusce eu bibendum dui. Praesent sit amet arcu ac risus efficitur maximus et id tellus. Cras vitae volutpat augue, id sollicitudin magna. Sed scelerisque dictum sem vitae maximus. Vestibulum tempus iaculis mauris, quis dapibus lorem fermentum in. Nullam vitae congue neque. Praesent condimentum hendrerit placerat. Suspendisse mattis eu leo eget efficitur. Suspendisse tortor odio, ornare sit amet varius vel, gravida sed dui. Quisque ultrices, dui ac aliquam pretium, orci sem tempor arcu, vitae maximus elit ipsum porttitor sem</p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle" data-action="more">Show More</a>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(".container").toggleClass("more");

    if($(this).attr('data-action') == 'more')    {
        $(this).html('Show Less');
        $(this).attr('data-action', 'less');


    } else {
        $(this).html('Show More');
        $(this).attr('data-action', 'more');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 18em;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee {
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.more {
    height: 8em;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { top:   2em }
    100% { top: -11em }
}
```

The key things to look in the CSS code are the animation related code and @keyframes which define where the text starts and ends.